# What is The Redirect?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In season 7 episode 7 Negan's group mentions something called The Redirect. What is this? I don't remember this being mentioned in earlier episodes.

Comment: Do you have a rough timeframe for when this is said?  I don't recall it but maybe if I saw the full context it's possible I might realize.  And I'm just curious.  But I don't want to watch the whole ep again. ;)

Comment: They mention it several times in the episode because the guy who got <spoiler>'d skipped out on The Redirect to be with someone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Redirect** is a way for The Saviours to maintain security and **lower walker density** in close proximity to their main base.

Using sound and people to get the "herd" going away from the path that leads to settlements.

**We saw The Saviours use this method in a previous show where they herded a "fairly small" group of zombies to the Hilltop community.**

Walkers generate sound. That in turn attracts more walkers and over time small groups get bigger and bigger. the biggest ones, **"the herds/superherds"** are too large to take head on so he easiest thing to do is to stay away from these.

As zombies cant think it is fairly easy to get attention of a group of them. Get a few to start following and more will notice. Those too start following and pretty soon you got a very big group following you.

In order for a **redirect** to be successful you have to be aware of your geography and point the big herds away from hills, mountains and the like.

**Just like Ricks group did in the previous season. They looked at maps and had Daryl and some others drive very slow in front of the leading edge of the zombie super herd making noise al the time. While making sure that the herd was moving downhill and towards open territory.**

We have also seen **The Redirect** in the beginning of this season done by that "all female" group. They had bells all around the camp so they could redirect any zombies away from them and in so doing keep their immediate area Zombie free.